# Bootstrap 4 remove margin for element via media query

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, margin, responsive

I'm trying to remove the margin mt-2 that I added in the nav-link element via media query in CSS when using mobile screen, but can't achieve that. It could be possible that I'm calling the class incorrectly.

See example here>:
[image]

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {

   .nav-link hovtext p-1 mt-2 a{
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4   d-flex clearfix">
          <nav class="nav flex-column footerstyle">
            <a class="nav-link hovtext p-1 mt-2" href="#">Términos de uso</a>
            <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">Políticas de privacidad</a>
            <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">Socios</a>
            <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">Confianza y Seguridad</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: 1. `mt-2` is already a native bootstrap 4 class, so I don't understand why you're manually adding it. 2. What do you want your element to look like? Must it have a top margin on a small screen and not on a larger one? Or the other way around?

Comment: 1.I'm adding the margin for that element only for a large screen as desktop 2. Must have a top margin in a large screen and in a small screen must be removed. It is possible to remove added bootstrap classes via mediaquery?

Comment: class name not mentioned properly. Class name should represented with '.' before the class name

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use the responsive `mt-lg-2` class instead of `mt-2`.

That will add the top margin for screens that are large (`lg`) or larger (i.e. those starting at 992px). And for smaller screens, it will default to zero margin.

In other words, that would be the same as adding the classes `mt-0 mt-lg-2`.

So, **you don't need any custom css or media queries for that**. The native Bootstrap 4 class `mt-lg-2` is designed to do exactly what you are trying to do. The spacing classes in Bootstrap 4 are responsive classes already. You don't need (and shouldn't) use any custom css for those simple tasks.

Here's a working snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 d-flex clearfix">
    <nav class="nav flex-column footerstyle">
        <a class="nav-link hovtext p-1 mt-lg-2" href="#">Términos de uso</a>
        <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">Políticas de privacidad</a>
        <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">Socios</a>
        <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">Confianza y Seguridad</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Also, important:

The `col-xs-*` class group doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4 (anymore). Use `col-*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

why you are mentioning all the classes? Ref the below code. And you have not mentioned hovtext as class. Class should be represented with '.' before the class name.

i.e `.hovtext{...}`

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {

   .hovtext{
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

If the above code not working means then mark it as important.

i.e. `margin:0 !important;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare the class manually, since it already has breakpoint-related options, ranging from `mt-#` to `mt-xl-#`. So what you want, according to your comment is to have a top margin on a large screen and none in a small one. And you follow the Bootstrap convention of writing from the smallest breakpoint to the largest one, so it would look like this.

```html
    <!-- 'mt' for the smallest breakpoint (xs) and mt-md for anything with a
        larger size than equal a medium-sized screen (md) -->
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4 d-flex clearfix">
        <nav class="nav flex-column footerstyle">
            <a class="nav-link hovtext p-1 mt-0 mt-md-2" href="#">Términos de uso</a>
            <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">Políticas de privacidad</a>
            <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">Socios</a>
            <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">Confianza y Seguridad</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

If you need it to be applied in a bigger breakpoint, just change the 'md' in the `mt-md-2` class to whichever breakpoint you want.